# Using character # in SQL query request with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, google-bigquery

I am using PHP for sending query request to GoogleBigQuery sql database.

The request would be similar like this:

```
SELECT namedcoord, COUNT(*)
FROM (
    select REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_EXTRACT(SPLIT(V2Locations,';'),r'^[2-5]#(.*?#.*?#.*?#.*?#.*?#.*?)#'), '^(.*?)#.*?#.*?#.*?#(.*?)#(.*?)', '\1;\2;\3') as namedcoord
    from [gdelt-bq:gdeltv2.gkg] 
    where DATE>20150302000000 and DATE < 20150304000000 and V2Persons like '%Tsipras%'
)
where namedcoord is not null
group by namedcoord
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 100
```

However, PHP can't handle the character `#` because it's treated as comment syntax.
Does anyone can help solve this problem?

Comment: As long as it's inside quotes it should work fine.. please edit your question to include the actual php code you are running and show us what error (if any) you get

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! After reading your comment, I have found that my $query is using '' (the single quotation) as well rather than "" (the double quotation) and also other variables that are quoted. It works after modifying all that quotations I have used. Thanks again!